# Real-time outdoor 3D mapping technology

Tags: 3d-scanner

I'm doing research on improving augmented reality experience and I'm searching for a technology, available commercially, that would offer a real-time 3D map of the environment.

Let me paint you a picture. I have an outdoor area in a form of a rectangle, 20x30 meters. In that area there is a person wearing one of the available VR headset that has two cameras on it, feeding the image to the headset. Now I need to place objects into the environment. Current prototypes have trouble correcting positioning the object in the real environment.

My idea is to use 3D mapping technology to solve this issue.

The scanners would be placed on key locations around the perimeter giving mesh or a point clout of the environment with decent refresh rate (few times per second would be nice).

Do you have any suggestions on the available technology that could be used? (cost is not an issue)